# Create some script for printing out several webpages

Tags: shell, html, printing-web-page, webpage-rendering

I have these webpages with content that I want to print out. I could go to each webpage and just choose to print it. But I thought that it would be more fun and maybe a little useful, atleast for me; to have some script that I can run that just goes prints each page.

If I input each page that I want to print and the script goes through them and for each page it renders it and prints it. Does someone know how I could achieve this? What programming would suit this best? 
Could I do it with some shell script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Alternatively, you could probably script it using JavaScript in a fake page and load this page into a web browser on the command line.